# Does anybody have a complete example of this "Spring Boot w/ JPA & H2: DB file created but nothing is persisted"

Tags: spring, h2

I am trying to follow these steps:

[Spring Boot w/ JPA & H2: DB file created but nothing is persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568707/spring-boot-w-jpa-h2-db-file-created-but-nothing-is-persisted?newreg=231e85b65c274ddfb4508a292476f1f8)

The database is created and it is populated with data but when the application ends the data is removed. I have tried various transactional solutions.

If I could get a complete example I would be greatfull.

Regards

ANders

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703988/file-based-h2-persisted-but-not-loaded-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using this configuration for my database:

```
spring.datasource.continueOnError=true
spring.datasource.dbCreate=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:./database/database_name;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

Comment: Where are you adding this configuration?  Is this in the application.context file?

Comment: I add it to  the application.properties file .